# Shell command (on Mac OSX El Capitan) to recursively rename all my DOCX files

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

I am trying to build a shell command (on Mac OSX El Capitan) to recursively rename all my DOCX files to have extension ZZZZ and then to immediately rename them back again to the DOCX extension.  This is a workaround to hopefully fix a problem as follows:

I am doing this to try to get around a Mac Spotlight bug which doesn't search for content inside Mac Word 2011 files correctly.  It gives intermittent results and seem to miss a lot of hits (this issue seem to be well-known for a few years on Apple Mac Forums). Renaming a file seems to kick-start Spotlight into action.

Mac Shell doesn't have the BASH Rename command so I am trying to iteratively use the "MV" command.  I've had partial success with the following code but don't know how to tie it together...

```
cd ~/Documents/TESTING/

# FINDS MY DOCX'S RECURSIVELY IN TOP-LEVEL FOLDER AND IT'S SUBFOLDERS.  NOT SURE OF SYNTAX TO USE FOR "MV" COMMAND TO RENAME DOCX FILES
# find . -wholename '*.docx' -type f -exec mv UNSURE1HERE UNSURE2HERE \;

# WORKS BUT ONLY IN TOP-LEVEL FOLDER - I NEED IT TO WORK RECURSIVELY ON DOCX'S IN  TOP-LEVEL FOLDER AND IT'S SUBFOLDERS:
# for files in *.docx; do mv "$files" "${files%.docx}.zzzz"; done
```

Comment: Will simply changing the modification time of the file cause it to be reindexed? It would be much simpler to use `touch` on each file than trying to rename them twice: `find . -wholename '*.docx' -type f -exec touch {} +`

Comment: Not sure it would be a reliable fix to Apple/Microsoft's Spotlight bug.  I also want to preserve the time & date metadata.  I don't see a downside to renaming the extension "twice".  Speed is not a big issue. Thanks.

Comment: "Mac Shell doesn't have the BASH Rename command": the default shell on OS X has always been bash. And renaming files on *nix has always been done with `mv`. Also, you may want to look at the `mdutil` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Documents/TESTING/

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo mv -- "$file" "${file%.*}.zzzzz"
done < <(find . -iname '*.docx' -type f -print0)
```

If you're satisfied with the output then remove `echo` before `mv`

From `.zzzz` to `.docx`:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo mv -- "$file" "${file%.*}.docx"
done < <(find . -iname '*.zzzz' -type f -print0)
```

Comment: It's giving this error message:  unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: Thanks - it mostly works.  2 issues:  1) how to find "docx" string irrespective of case.  2) how to rename back from zzzz to docx.  I tried #2 with code below and not working.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

cd ~/Documents/TESTING/

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
     mv -- "$file" "${file%.docx}.zzzzz"
     mv -- "$file" "${file%.zzzzz}.docx"
done < <(find . -name '*.docx' -type f -print0)

Comment: when it sees testing99.DOCX (upper case ext) it results in testing99.DOCX.zzzzz  rather than replacing DOCX

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks.